# i++ loops without any problem, i+2 loops infinitely and crashes

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop

I want to create a simple loop function that adds 2 every time it loops. However, even though I tell my for loop to stop if the number reaches or is less than 100, it goes past 100 and loops infinitely.

i++ works just fine:

```
function addTwo() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

addTwo();
```

When I change it to i+2 it crashes:

```
function addTwo() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 100; i + 2) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

addTwo();
```

I expect the console to log:
0
2
4
6
8
...
100.

But instead it loops infinitely and crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i+2` in your case does nothing. JS evaluates it and then does nothing with the calculated value, this means that `i` is never increased.

`++` is a special operator that increments the variable preceding it by 1.

To make the loop work you have to assign the value of the calculation `i+2` to the variable `i`.

```
for (i=0; i<=100; i = i+2) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

**or**

```
for (i=0; i<=100; i += 2) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`i++` increments `i`. But, `i+2` doesn't update the value of `i`. You should change it to `i += 2`

```js
function addTwo() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 100; i += 2) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

addTwo();
```

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of a `for` is the [final-expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

> An expression to be evaluated at the end of each loop iteration. This occurs before the next evaluation of condition. Generally used to update or increment the counter variable.

In your case you are not assigning any value to `i`. You should replace it with something like this:

```
function addTwo() {
  for (i=0; i<=100; i+=2) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

addTwo();
```

Answer (score 1):

`i++` is a short hand for `i += 1` which is called [Increment Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()) But `i+2` or even `i+1` will not increase the value of `i`. You need to increase it by assigning a new value to i. `i = i + 2` or `i += 2`.

Number is one of the primitive types in javascript which mean you can't change it unless you use assignment operator `=`

**Note**: You are not using `let` or `var` with `i` this will make `i` a global variable.

```js
function addTwo() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i+=2) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

addTwo();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    console.log(i);        
     i++;
}
```

You can increase i twice Or

```
for (i=0; i<=100; i+=2) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

you can use i+=2 it will increase value of i 2 times and set new value of i.